# Updated from 15.10 to 16.04, now don't have sound!

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa, jack

I had spent some time a while ago getting Jack to work on 15.10 so I could use SuperCollider and Sonic-Pi but when I upgraded my sound is now broken! Tried the Alsa troubleshooter, nothing.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, I found another driver under the "additional drivers" tool which I selected. After restart it worked. Also had to do it for my video card. You can find the tool by opening the dash, then just type add.

Comment: Can't seem to find that tool either! I know it was the last tab on the update settings set of windows, and that I could get to it through the software center or through settings, but settings is no longer opening for me and Gnome (which I'm using instead of Unity) replaced the Ubuntu Software Center with a more generic Gnome version which doesn't allow me to get to that bunch of settings!

Comment: You can try to type in the command line "software-properties-gtk" then click the additional drivers tab. It is however less common to have additional drivers for the sound than other hardware.

Comment: Also I think you can type "gnome-volume-control" to open gnome sound settings with gnome